# how to get innerHTML of a Combobox in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, combobox, innerhtml

this is my function that fills the combobox (its id is bc)

```
function fillComboBox() {
  for(let i=0; i < SemanticTaskPropertySet.types.length; i++) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = SemanticTaskPropertySet.types[i].bc;
    option.value = SemanticTaskPropertySet.types[i].bc_id;
    bc.appendChild(option);
    let option2 = document.createElement("option");
    option2.innerHTML = SemanticTaskPropertySet.types[i].ti;
    option2.value = SemanticTaskPropertySet.types[i].ti;
    ti.appendChild(option2);
  }
}
```

the value for the line:

```
option.value = SemanticTaskPropertySet.types[i].bc_id;
```

I get with bc.value;

but how can I get the value for the line?

```
option.innerHTML = SemanticTaskPropertySet.types[i].bc;
```

I tried: bc.innerHTML; but that doesn't work.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.text` attribute `option` elements:

```
option.text = SemanticTaskPropertySet.types[i].bc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `option.text` for inner text ( innerHTML ) of `option`

`option.value` for `value="1"`

```js
function getTextFunc(x) {
  console.log(x.options[x.selectedIndex].text);
}


let elem = document.getElementById("myElem")

getTextFunc(elem)
```

```html
<select id="myElem">
  <option value="1"> Option Text 1</option>
  <option value="2"> Option Text 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much!
option.text = SemanticTaskPropertySet.types[i].bc;
and then bc.options[bc.selectedIndex].text;
works perfectly fine